# field not found according to npgsql, but it exists according to pgadmin

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, pgadmin

I have this line of code as my query in C#:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * 
                   FROM product 
                   LEFT JOIN category ON product.category_id = category.id 
                   WHERE product.id = @productId";
```

The `product` table has a column called `name` which I need.

This is the line I use in my application to retrieve it.

```
product.ProductName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("\"product\".\"name\""));
```

The error I'm getting is

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Field not found

on that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reader.GetOrdinal("name");
```

Firstly the resultset does not have a field named `"product"."name"`, but rather one named `"name"`. Consider that if you were to try to select from that resultset within PostgreSQL it would be the same case:

```
SELECT "product"."name" FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM product 
    LEFT JOIN category ON product.category_id = category.id 
    WHERE product.id = @productId) subquery
```

Doesn't work, but:

```
SELECT "name" FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM product 
    LEFT JOIN category ON product.category_id = category.id 
    WHERE product.id = @productId) subquery
```

Does.

Secondly, don't use the PostgreSQL escaping on the name of the field.

Comment: Actually, that's not true. I just did it in pgadmin. It works over there. I need it here because category also has a name field. And I don't only need the name. I need all the data of both rows.

Comment: Really, you did exactly the same code as my first example and it worked? Anyway, if you need to columns to have different names, give one or both of them a different name.

Comment: I fixed with specifying the exact columns in the querry and then giving this one an alias.

Comment: A typing short-cut would have been `SELECT product.name as prod_name, category.name as cat_name, *` and just live with the duplication. It's slightly less efficient because you are still getting the other copies of those two fields, but it makes it less of a chore if there are lots of fields.